# Enemy´s shoot player´ 2 times instead of 1 time .But I only want the 1 Bullet shot down and not 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm a beginner in python/pygame and new here on the page. I have the following problem:
My player class reaches the detection radius of my Enemy class!
This shoots on the player, every 2 seconds, but not 1 bullet but 2 at a time, or with 0.1 second offset!
But I only want the 1 Bullet shot down and not 2!
The code I have from the creator: Kidscancode (https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCNaPQ5uLX5iIEHUCLmfAgKg)!
Unfortunately, he does not answer my mail that I sent a month ago!
Can you please look at my code and tell me where I have a mistake?
(Coming from Germany, translated text with translator)

Enemy-Klass:

```
import pygame as pg
from settings import *
from sprites import *
from random import randint, uniform
vec = pg.math.Vector2

class Mob(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, x, y):
        self.groups = game.all_sprites, game.mobs
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
        self.game = game
        self.image = pg.Surface((140, 20))
        self.image.fill(RED)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2)
        self.pos = vec(x, y) * TILESIZE
        self.rect.x = x * TILESIZE
        self.rect.y = y * TILESIZE
        self.rotate_time = pg.time.get_ticks()

        self.target = game.player
        self.health = MOB_HEALTH

        self.last_shot = 0

    def shoot(self):
        Mob_bullet(self.game)

    def rotate(self,angle):
        now = pg.time.get_ticks()
        if now - self.rotate_time > 50:
            self.rotate_time = pg.time.get_ticks()
            newimage = pg.transform.rotate(self.image, angle)
            oldcenter = self.rect.center
            self.image = newimage
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            self.rect.center = oldcenter

    def update(self):
         target_dist = self.target.pos - self.pos
         if target_dist.length_squared() < DETECT_RADIUS ** 2:
             now = pg.time.get_ticks()
             if now - self.last_shot > MOB_BULLET_RATE:
                 self.last_shot = now
                 self.shoot()


class Mob_bullet(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game):
        self.groups = game.all_sprites
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
        self.game = game
        self.image = pg.Surface((10, 10))
        self.image.fill(ORANGE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.pos = vec(800, 400)
        self.vel = vec(MAX_SPEED, 0).rotate(uniform(0, 180))
        self.acc = vec(0, 0)
        self.rect.center = self.pos

        "'spawntime ist wichtig für Lifetime der Bullets!'"
        self.spawn_time = pg.time.get_ticks()



    def seek(self, target):
        self.desired = (target - self.pos).normalize() * MAX_SPEED
        steer = (self.desired - self.vel)
        if steer.length() > SEEK_FORCE:
            steer.scale_to_length(SEEK_FORCE)
        return steer


    def update(self):
        "'Geschwindigkeit = suche nach(Target)'"
        self.acc = self.seek(self.game.player.pos)

        "'Bewegungsgleichung'"
        self.vel += self.acc
        if self.vel.length() > MAX_SPEED:
            self.vel.scale_to_length(MAX_SPEED)
        self.pos += self.vel

        self.rect.center = self.pos

        "'Kollission mit Walls'"
        if pg.sprite.spritecollideany(self, self.game.walls):
            self.kill()

        "'Lebenszeit von Bullets'"
        if pg.time.get_ticks() - self.spawn_time > MOB_BULLET_LIFETIME:
            self.kill()
```

A part of the Main-File:

```
 class Game:
        def new(self):
        self.all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()
        .......
        self.Mob_bullets = pg.sprite.Group()
```

A part of the Setting-File:

```
 "'Bullet-Settings'"
 MOB_BULLET_LIFETIME = 5000
 MOB_BULLET_RATE = 2000
 MOB_BULLET_DMG = 20
 MAX_SPEED = 5
 SEEK_FORCE = 3
```

I can not deliver an error message because the game works.
I've been learning python (my very first programming language) for only 3 months. please do not use too many technical terms;)   !

One more thing, it's not a display bug, there are 2 bullets (Rects) coming out, which are counted!

Comment: Please post a [minimal, runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That will make it a lot easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggesting printing information to the console when the event is triggered. If you print environmental variables each time a bullet is fired, that may give you some clues. You can also print messages like "player in range" when certain conditions are met. You may see a pattern that doesn't match what you were trying for, which will narrow down which part of the code has an error.

Comment: Thank you for your quick advice, Mr. Speidell! I will add some variables and print them out to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Found a mistake. There was a typo(typing error) in the map.txt file.
Instead of an Enemy I had 2 next to each other! so the code is fine!